# how to use built in list function "filter"

Tags: list, filter, scheme

Please help me with using the DrScheme built-in function "filter".

"create a function "hello" that consumes a number 'Max', and a list of numbers 'L', produce a list of numbers in 'L' that are smaller than 'Max'."

**edit** Taken from the comments for formatting

this is what i have so far

```
(define (smaller? n Max) 
  (cond 
    [(> Max n) n] 
    [else empty])) 
(define (hello Max L) 
  (filter smaller? L))
```

I don't know how to implement Max into the function hello.

Comment: why don't you show us what you've done so far, and where you are getting stuck?

Comment: this is what i have so far

 
(define (smaller? n Max)
   (cond
      [(> Max n) n]
      [else empty]))


(define (hello Max L)
   (filter smaller? L))
 
i dont know how to implement Max into the function hello

Comment: (qrsvar (uryyb znk y) (svygre (ynzoqn (k) (> znk k)) y)) :-P

Comment: To help your answer a bit, have you learnt about closures yet? This problem is not really solvable without using closures.

Comment: You don't need closures for this.

Comment: @Svante: The "lambda inside a function which sees things in the function's scope" _is_ a closure. :-)

Comment: OK, if you look at the core of it, perhaps, but you don't have to learn about closures to apply this, and Ben certainly is not helped by the notion that closures might have something to do with his problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your `smaller?` definition, I would go for something like

```
(define (hello Max L)
  (filter (lambda (n) (smaller? n Max)) L))
```

This uses a lambda function which is a closure over the Max argument to the hello function. So it "embeds" `Max` inside the lambda function used for filtering.

Comment: Thank you for agreeing with me about what a closure is. :-)

Comment: Of course, the `smaller?` function is completely superfluous.

Comment: this is what i end up with in the end

    (define (hello Max L)
      (filter (smaller Max) L))

    (define (smaller Max)
      (lambda (n)
        (< n Max)))

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can create an anonymous function with `lambda`:

```
(lambda (x) (have-fun-with x))
```

*edit:* Another hint: `(> Max n)` already returns a boolean, you don't need an enclosing `cond` structure.

Comment: my problem is that im not sure how i can do it without using Max in the lambda

Comment: or rather, the predicate inside filter only consumes one thing, but i have two things, 'Max' and 'L', so i dont know how to work around that

Comment: If you use the lambda inside a function, it sees everything in that function's scope.

Comment: @Ben: You work around that by using a closure. Example: (lambda (foo) (lambda (bar) (+ foo bar))). The inner lambda can access the "foo" in the outer lambda. Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you guys, your discussion of closure really helped, i looked into it and found out what to do